# Append items within a list to Polars Daraframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-polars

I would like to append or concatenate horizontally list of items to Polars based daraframe through for loop.

In pandas -

```
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

add_list = [(10, 100, 'd'), (20, 20, 'D')]

df1_pd = pd.DataFrame({ "a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [6, 7, 8], "c": ["a", "b", "c"]})

for d in add_list:
    ser_pd = pd.Series(data=d, index=df1_pd.columns)
    df1_pd = pd.concat([df1_pd, ser_pd.to_frame().T], ignore_index=True)
```

Gives desired output -

[image]

How to achieve the same in polars?

```
df2_pl = pl.DataFrame({ "a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [6, 7, 8], "c": ["a", "b", "c"]})

for d in add_list:
    ser_pl = pl.Series(values=d, dtype=pl.Object)
    # next ??
```

**Solution (for the sake of completeness) -

```
for d in add_list:
    arr = np.asarray(d).reshape(-1, len(d))
    df2_pl = pl.concat([df2_pl, pl.DataFrame(arr, schema=df2_pl.schema)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest not using a for-loop here, this is the kind of pattern why `append` was deprecated in pandas

You can do:

```py
In [7]: pl.concat([df2_pl, pl.DataFrame(add_list, schema=df2_pl.schema)])
Out[7]:
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 6   ┆ a   │
│ 2   ┆ 7   ┆ b   │
│ 3   ┆ 8   ┆ c   │
│ 10  ┆ 100 ┆ d   │
│ 20  ┆ 20  ┆ D   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```